# Traverse HTML file elements with PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

I need to read an HTML file (that I don't know how it will look like) and go through all its elements. For those elements that have an innerhtml text, I'd like to grab or modify that. I've searched exhaustively but can't find something that does what I need.

Here's an example HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
   <p> 1st text I need</p>
   <a href="#">2nd text I need</a>
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td>3rd text I need</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what I need to accomplish:

1. Traverse file
2. Find which elements have innerhtml
3. Grab or modify the text
4. Save the file

In the file above almost all elements have text but complex files won't.
I can use DOMDocument() to loop through specific types of nodes but I don't know what I'm going to encounter until a file is selected. 
I thought the code below would do it but it prints just the file name during the loop.

```
<?php
include 'functions.php';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('test.html');
showDOMNode($doc);  

function showDOMNode($domNode) {

    foreach ($domNode->childNodes as $node)
    {
        if($node->nodeName !="#text") {
            echo $node->nodeName . ' ';
            echo $node->nodeType . ' ';
            echo $node->textContent . '<br>';

            if($node->hasChildNodes()) {
                showDOMNode($node);
            }
        }
    }    
}           
?>
```

Here's what I get:

```
html 10
html 1 1st text I need 2nd text I need 3rd text I need
body 1 1st text I need 2nd text I need 3rd text I need
p 1 1st text I need
a 1 2nd text I need
table 1 3rd text I need
tr 1 3rd text I need
td 1 3rd text I need
```

As you can see, when the textContent seems to show the text for all child nodes while I need the specific one for each node. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I highly recommend [simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). It uses a jQuery like selector to make it much easier to traverse the dom.

Comment: I've looked into that and I can't see how to traverse the whole file. I'll check again.